# Cannot Mount Local Directory to torchserve docker container

Tags: windows, docker, powershell, pytorch, torchserve

Please bear with me as I am new to docker and have never used torchserve before, so any feedback will help. I am trying to create a .mar file in an existing docker container from a model.pt file, handler file, and index to label mapping json file. I have already pulled the torchserve docker image from docker hub, and can successfully run it. I have tried mounting a local directory to the container, but the directory doesn't appear in the container. In windows command prompt I have tried:

**docker run -it -v C:\Users<restofabsolutepath>:/src pytorch/torchserve:latest-cpu bash**

After this command, I search the container, and cannot find the src folder or any of its contents in the container. I am on a windows machine if that makes any difference in how I should approach this.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the Docker torchserve container starts with `/home/model-server` as the root folder. So you are better off mounting local volumes off that as:

`docker run --rm -it -p 8080:8080 -p 8081:8081 --name mar -v $(pwd)/model-store:/home/model-server/model-store -v $(pwd)/examples:/home/model-server/examples pytorch/torchserve:latest`

See step 1 listed [here](https://github.com/pytorch/serve/blob/master/docker/README.md#create-torch-model-archiver-from-container) for more details. Hope that helps.